# Short story where man becomes convinced that if he falls asleep he will die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story on the internet where teleportation technology is invented. The main character decries the new technology  and refuses to use it because it causes a gap in consciousness, and thus results in the death of the person who uses it.

He eventually has the realisation (he might have come to this realisation after a debate with an advocate of the teleportation technology, but I'm unsure of this) that if a gap in consciousness is fatal, he dies and is reborn every time he goes to sleep. He then tries to avoid sleeping for as long as he can before eventually succumbing.

I cannot remember what happens after he falls asleep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if it counts as a short story, but this the plot of [The Machine](https://existentialcomics.com/comic/1), the first posting of [Existential Comics](https://existentialcomics.com/).

The viewpoint character indeed decries the new technology as mass murder, and then progresses to viewing each night's sleep as the ending of a particular self.  He tries staying awake, then partying, and finally comes to terms with himself being merely one of a succession of consciousnesses that each inherit memories from their predecessors.

Comment: This is it, thank you. I completely forgot about the visual element!

Comment: FWIW, this was also the basis of a 2014 SMBC strip, https://selfawarepatterns.com/2014/11/17/smbc-so-how-long-do-we-live/